# What does "karma" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Danny: You kicked me off the building?
>   Ward: Of course I did.
>   It's what you do when you see someone trying to break in.
>   Danny: You are really pushing the limits of **karma**.

Source: Iron Fist, episode 4

**What does "karma" mean?**

I checked it in dictionary, but it doesn't fit the above context.

> karma: (in the Buddhist and Hindu religions) the force produced by a person's actions in one life that influences what happens to them in future lives. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/karma?fallbackFrom=british-grammar)

Comment: It fits pretty well actually.  Danny is basically a Buddhist having spent the last 15 years in a temple.  He's saying that Ward's action is making it really hard to believe something bad hasn't happened to him.  Either from the universe, or Danny taking action, because he's been mistreating Danny since they were children.

Answer (score 1):

Although the above is the strict definition of **karma**, it's also used to describe the general belief that one gets what they deserve.

In your example, Ward kicks Danny off the building because *"It's what you do when you see someone trying to break in."* - he believes that Danny deserves this for his actions. Danny seems to see this as an extreme response to his actions, and believes that Ward is *"pushing the limits of karma"*.